# Firebase slow image reading

Tags: android, firebase-storage

I am facing difficulty loading images from firebase storage. It takes too long, and sometimes the app crashes while reading them. Is there any potential solution for this? I am using android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Your internet connection is slow, I think and when your app crashes check your LogCat for errors